How to prove the exisitence of $x_1$?
For $N$ sequence of probability density functions $\{f_n^i(x)\}, i=1,\ldots,N$, where $f_n^i(x)$ is continuous, positive everywhere and bounded by a large real number $\mathcal{M}$. We define a normalized probability density function $F^*(x)$ as:
$$ F^*(x) = \frac{\prod_{i=1}^N (f_0^i(x))^{\frac{1}{N}}}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \prod_{i=1}^N (f_0^i(x))^\frac{1}{N} \, dx} $$
and:
$$
    f_n^i(x) = \frac{\prod_{j=1}^N (f_{n-1}^j(x))^{a_j}}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \prod_{j=1}^N (f_{n-1}^j(x))^{a_j} \, dx}
$$
where $\sum_{j=1}^N a_j = 1$. Prove whether, for a given $i$, there exists an $x_1$ such that
$$
    \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n^i(x_1) = F^*(x_1).
$$

Presumably we want to assume something about the intersections of the supports of the pdfs, otherwise the products could be identically zero. Also, your definition of $f^i_n$ doubles up on the use of $i$.

Thank you for your answer! I supplemented some conditions about the PDFs and corrected the issues you mentioned. I apologize for my carelessness.

How are you taking $n\to\infty$ when you have only N pdfs? If there are infinitely many pdfs then how will you define $F^\ast$?

Surely, $N$ is just the number of pdfs used at step $n$.

@PNDas At every step ($n=0,1,2,\ldots$), there are $N$ pdfs.

The definition of $f^i_n$ does not depend on $i$. This means $f^1_n=f^2_n=\ldots = f^N_n$. From this we can see that $f^i_n=f^1_1$ for all $n=1,2,\ldots$ and $i=1,2,\ldots, N$. Am I reading this correctly? If so, the limit doesn't matter. We only compare $F^*$ to $f^1_1$.

But they are not always equal......they may be distinct
